# Killing Game Enemies ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, game-development

They're not really enemies, they are just balloons that you shoot.  However, when they get added with addChild, none of them are playing their "death" animations when I click on (shoot) them.  Here is my code. Please excuse me if it appears disorganized, I just started ActionScript with no prior OOP experience.

Everything works fine except clicking on the children seems not to register at all to the objects added to the stage.  I have no external class and all my instance names are correct.  I called the balloons "victim" in the linkage.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


Mouse.hide();
cursor_mc.startDrag(true);


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);
shotHandler.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, boxShot);

function boxShot(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    enemyBox.gotoAndStop(2);
}




    function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void

    {
        cursor_mc.play();
        var myBullet:MovieClip = new black_mc();
        myBullet.x = mouseX; myBullet.y = mouseY;
        stage.addChildAt(myBullet , 0);
    }


    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1200, 300);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, createEnemies);
    myTimer.start();

    function createEnemies(e:Event):void
    {


        var circle:MovieClip = new victim();
        circle.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        circle.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
        addChildAt(circle , 2);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked your code and I don't see any addings of MouseListeners on your "victim" objects. Anyway, if you need to do something with object on clicking it, you may write something like this:

```
function createEnemies(e:Event):void //your enemy creation function
{


    var circle:MovieClip = new victim();

    circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onObjClick); // here is your click listener

    circle.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    circle.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    addChildAt(circle , 2);


}

private function onObjClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var target:MovieClip = event.currentTarget as victim;
    target.gotoAndPlay("destroyAnim");
    //target.goToDeath();  uncomment this and comment previous line if you already have a destroy function into your "victim" class.
}
```